# How to replace HTML in WordPress outside Contents?

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress, replace

I'd like to insert barba.js wrapper to enable barba around main tag.

Current code is like below.

```
<main>
    <article>
        ........
    </article>
</main>
```

And what I desire is like below.

```
<div id="barba-wrapper">
    <div class="barba-container">
        <main>
            <article>
                ........
            </article>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

If main tag is inside 'the_content' filter, I could code like below.

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content) {
    $content = str_replace('<div id="barba-wrapper"><div 
    class="barba-container"><main>', '<main>', $content);
    $content = str_replace('</main>', '</main></div></div>', $content);
    return $content;
});
```

However, `<main>` is not inside `the_content` filter, above function is not working.

Is there anyway to replace it? and is there any warning about this?

Comment: Hi @Emma, sorry for lack of information. I added the current code and desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that an expression similar to:

```
(<main>(.*?)<\/main>)
```

might work here.

#### TEST

```
$re = '/(<main>(.*?)<\/main>)/s';
$str = '

<main>

some content we wish goes here

</main>';
$subst = '<div id="barba-wrapper"><div class="barba-container">$1</div></div>';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

based on which our code might look like:

```
$re = '/(<main>(.*?)<\/main>)/s';
$subst = '<div id="barba-wrapper"><div class="barba-container">$1</div></div>';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $content);

echo $result;
```

[For additional explanation, please see this link.](https://regex101.com/r/geliWF/1/)